# Trust the Registry Keys or the Environment Variables

Tags: c++, winapi, registry, posix, environment-variables

I have a program I am making in C++ WinAPI & I need to determine the version of Windows the user is running & the path to Program Files.

I know I can determine this by looking at the Windows Environment Variables or the Registry Keys(can I get the path to program files from the Registry?) BUT which is better practice?

I know Environment Variables can be changed easily so its not good to trust them, but can the registry keys be changed as easily - which is better to trust?

Is it better practice to go to the Registry for this information or the Environment Variables? Which would you do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the [GetVersionEx Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724451%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API instead. It's better than the environment variable and the registry.

For the path to program files, there is also an API: [SHGetFolderPath Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762181%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)